# Using helm to manage an "environment?"

Tags: kubernetes, helm, kubernetes-helm

I'm new to Kubernetes, and hence helm, so I've been reading a lot, and teaching myself by setting up a cluster, services, deployments, and pods. In my case I use AWS EKS.

I now at least understand each piece from a technical point of view. But now I want to put it all together in managing an "environment." I believe this is the idea behind GitOps.

Say I'm a QA person and am testing a "staging" environment. This environment comprises a number of microservices with their own respective versions. So logically I can represent it this way

```
/staging-2021-03-06-4 # 4th build of staging environment on 2/06/2021
- microservice1:1.1.0
- microservice2:1.2.0
- microservice3:1.3.0
```

When we build the next staging, e.g, `staging-2021-03-06-5`, anyone of those microservices versions can change.

But now I, the QA guy, find an issue with above `staging-2021-03-06-4` build, and I ask a developer to look at it. I want to be able to just tell the developer to "check out" the `staging-2021-03-06-4` environment so he/she can have **exactly** the environment that I have to reproduce the issue.

I'm thinking I can set up this idea of "environment" with `helm`, since the "environment" is nothing but a package of packages? Is this the correct utility of `helm`? If so, do I just set up a `staging-2021-03-06-4` helm chart that has dependencies of other charts, and those other charts are for each microservice?

I'm also reading [How to manage 10+ team environments with Helm and Kubernetes?](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/6641/how-to-manage-10-team-environments-with-helm-and-kubernetes) since it applies to me also, but that describes a different (additional) problem I'm trying to solve with `helm`.

**Update**: I think I'm essentially wanting GitOps, so I'll read up on that.

Comment: We're building a tool as a layer on top of GitOps - https://relizahub.com - with the specific functionality you're asking about described here - https://github.com/relizaio/reliza-cli#72-use-case-replace-tags-on-deployment-templates-to-inject-correct-artifacts-for-gitops-using-instance-and-revision . It's an early stage for us, so feel free to connect if this resonates.

Comment: @taleodor I briefly checked it out, looks very useful so far. Thanks.

Comment: I'm currently studying https://github.com/fluxcd/helm-operator-get-started

Comment: Check ArgoCD as well, i.e. we have sample helm CD based on Argo here - https://gitlab.com/taleodor/sample-helm-cd/

Also feel free to connect with me - would be happy to discuss more - https://www.linkedin.com/in/pshukhman/

Comment: @taleodor, I sent you a LI connection request. I do have questions.

Answer (score 1):

Helm charts should not be built for a specific environment, IMHO. You can see that many of the official helm charts have a set of default values and they are configurable from outside. You also can create a helm chart like that and declare your deployment + environment-specific values with another tool like [Helm Operator](https://github.com/fluxcd/helm-operator) or [ArgoCD](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/). In this way, you can both simplify your build pipeline and increase [dev/prod parity](https://12factor.net/dev-prod-parity). You can use that one chart and **promote** the same build into different environments so you can be sure that different environments are identical except the configuration.

Example ArgoCD application manifests:

**production-application.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: production-yourservice
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/yourorganisation/helm-charts
    path: yourservice
    targetRevision: master
    helm:
      values: |
        environment: production
        replicas: 10
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: production-yourservice
```

**staging-application.yaml:**

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Application
metadata:
  name: staging-yourservice
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  project: default
  source:
    repoURL: https://github.com/yourorganisation/helm-charts
    path: yourservice
    targetRevision: master
    helm:
      values: |
        environment: staging
        replicas: 1
  destination:
    server: https://kubernetes.default.svc
    namespace: staging-yourservice
```

Comment: I personally do NOT like this solution at all since now I have to maintain multiple manifest files for multiple applications, different only in the environment they're deployed in.

Comment: @chris-f yes, duplicating the manifest files is not the way. You can use Helm chart of charts (I'm not a big fan) or putting together & overriding the manifest files with Kustomize, which I like to combine with ArgoCD.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could set up the "environments" as [Chart of charts](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/subcharts_and_globals/) using Helm
2. or (my prefered way) utilize [ArgoCD](https://argoproj.github.io/cd/) with [Kustomize](https://kustomize.io/) - having "default" manifest for each service, creating the "environment" with a Kustomize file, referencing the "default" manifests and overriding needed values.

(also see my other answer on [how to use ArgoCD](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/15698/8025))